# npm start showing weird error 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, command-line-interface

I am new to react js and I have installed the dependencies for the application. Below is my package file:

`package.json`

```
{
"name": "reactapp",
"version": "0.0.0",
"description": "learn and test",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
},
"author": "john doe",
"license": "BSD-2-Clause",
"dependencies": {
  "webpack": "~1.13.3",
  "webpack-dev-server": "~1.16.2",
  "react": "~15.3.2",
  "react-dom": "~15.3.2"
},
"devDependencies": {}
}
```

It throws the error:

```
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

But, in the terminal while it doesn't show up anything when in scripts it is

`"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"`

Comment: what command do you run that causes the error and what is your node version?

Comment: Try executing `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy` from your command line/shell.

Comment: @netchkin `npm start`

Comment: @DavidR It worked, buddy

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo Cool.. Can you please accept my answer then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `sudo` command while installing `nodejs-legacy`.

Executing `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy` from your command line/shell will resolve the issue.